# Mysql Group By not counting correctly

Tags: mysql

I have some login dates in a database and want to get some statistics grouped by date.

What I would like to have is:

```
2016-07-01 : 13 different users logged in
2016-07-02 : 9 different users logged in
2016-07-01 : 12 different users logged in
...
```

What I get so far:

```
2016-07-01 : 13 different users logged in
2016-07-02 : 13 different users logged in
2016-07-01 : 13 different users logged in
```

My query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) as num, zeitstempel
FROM log
WHERE zeitstempel BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 50 DAY) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
GROUP BY DATE(zeitstempel)
ORDER BY DATE(zeitstempel) ASC
```

Does anybody have a solution why this query is not working?

Comment: can you update the error message

Comment: @MaheshMadushanka Please spend some seconds more when [suggesting an edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13006414) to address the issue properly. Just adding 4 spaces without removing the ` is not really improving the formatting. Additionally, a notice like the one you introduced is not necessary because it can be seen in the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38374077/revisions). You will earn the privilege to single-handedly edit posts soon. Please use it wisely.

Comment: Note that zeitstempel will be indeterminate. And a result set with no data set is about as much fun as a stick without a lollipop.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) as num, zeitstempel FROM log 
WHERE zeitstempel BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 50 DAY) AND DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
GROUP BY DATE(zeitstempel) 
ORDER BY DATE(zeitstempel) ASC
```

You are using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP you have to use DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP).